# What will be faster for displaying data with ajax/php/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When making an Ajax call I could for example make a callback php function to display the html or the callback could callback a JSON and the display the data with jquery? is it the same? or which one is faster? or a more reliable way?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'callback php function'? PHP functions can't call back to javascript code...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your implementation.

If you are using a powerful server-side templating system like Twig, I would recommend that you let Twig handle the rendering and just display the new HTML in Javascript.

This avoids having to re-code in Javascript things that Twig is already doing.

If on the other hand you are talking about pure Javascript (think one-page application), then get some JSON and let the Javasript do the rendering.

The goal is always to "Don't Repeat Yourself". If you have all of your rendering logic in one language, always try to leverage it as much as possible instead of duplicating it, which would make updating it a pain.